# How to make text box scroll vertical in overflow css html?

Tags: html, css

This question might already have been asked before but I couldn't find one where it could help me. anyway, I've created a text box with following script:

css:

```css
.cln{
top:220px;
width:680px;
height:350px;
text-align:left;
overflow:scroll;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="cln" placeholder="That is my pet right there:)" maxlength="2024"/>
```

The problem is that the text box typing starts from the center `50% to 50%`and never scrolls to vertical scroll, As much as you type line goes horizontal.
But I want it to start from top left and never cross the text box borders.
All I could do so far is to change, remove `white-space overflow text-align` and so, But none helped.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You should use `textarea` for that.

Comment: try adding textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `textarea` like below. It will auto scroll

```html
This will scroll automatically...<br/>
<textarea type="text" class="cln" placeholder="That is my pet right there:)" col=30 rows=10> </textarea>
```

Comment: line is still not scrolling vertical, still goes horizontal

Comment: @John, check it out again

Comment: O.k just figured it out, had to remove `white-space` in my css, anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use textarea not input

```
<textarea  class="cln" placeholder="That is my pet right there:)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use textarea instead of input?

```
<textarea type="text" class="cln" placeholder="That is my pet right there:)" maxlength="2024"/></textarea>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/desig9stein/pen/XNWeXM)